# Filing remaining space with form inputs

Tags: css, forms, css-float

Okay so say I have a form element like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label>Current password</label>
    <input id="edit-current-pass" class="form-text" type="password" maxlength="128" size="25" name="current_pass" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="description">lorum ispum</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.description {
    clear: both;
}

label {
    float: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 140px;
}
form input.form-text {
    background-image: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

Is it possible to make it so the input takes up the **remaining width** of the line besides the left floated label element?

(FYI the parent container has a width set to it).

I'd like to make this responsive so the form grows and shrinks to the browser window.

Comment: I don't think this is possible purely with CSS and HTML. Is a JS solution acceptable?

Comment: Is using table layout out of the question? Then maybe you may want to take a look at [css box flex](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this might not be possible with purely HTML/CSS, but I managed it with an additional wrapper around the input box. [Check it out on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwm5V/2/).

## HTML

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label for="edit-current-pass">Current password</label>
    <span class="input">
        <input id="edit-current-pass" type="password" maxlength="128" size="25" name="current_pass" autocomplete="off">
    </span>
    <div class="description">lorum ispum</div>
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
.description {
    clear: both;
}

label {
    float: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 140px;
}
.input {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.input input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}​
```

Comment: I've just edited it with a parent container so I can change the width. Now it doesn't seem to work... http://jsfiddle.net/hwm5V/3/